# Using ODWEK odconfig to connect to Infopac server

Tags: java, mainframe, ondemand

I'm working on part of migration project in which while click on search - through webservice call the PDF is pulled from ondemand server and through another webservice call PDF is taked from Infopac server ( so the pdf may come from any of the two servers ). 
Now part of migration the webservice used to pull pdf from Infopac is going to shutdown due to business reasons.

On thing we try now is to try to connect to Infopac using ODWEK ( odconfig used for ondemand ) along with API used for ondemand.

**Is it possible to connect with same odconfig used for Ondemand server to Infopac server with infopac server details.**

**Is ODWEK is specific to Ondemand?** if yes then please suggest me or show me the way with some link. yes ofcourse referred to some IBM links before jumping to stackoverflow.

Any of your help is appreciated!

Thankyou!